# No overload for method takes 1 argument error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add up all my values of listbox1 but I get an error message.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal sum = 0;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
        Listbox1opgeteld(sum); //*this is the error

    }
    public decimal Listbox1opgeteld(int random, decimal sum)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items);
            sum += Convert.ToDecimal(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());

        }
        return sum;

    }
```

I tried other question threads but can't find an answer, would really appreciate your help!

Comment: You can't call the method `Listbox1opgeteld` with two parameters if it only takes one. You don't need the second one.

Comment: You need to provide two arguments, not only one

Comment: @CodeJoy Please keep it in english. Non dutchies won't benefit from dutch answers.

Comment: @CodeJoy English please.

Comment: Did you try to read the error message? It is very clear and informative

Comment: Please get a good book first. This question is more than basic, something that every good book covers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a basic book would cover this.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using `random` inside method so you can remove it from parameter and use temporary local variable for manipulating `sum` value

```
public decimal Listbox1opgeteld(decimal sum)
    {
        decimal temp = sum;

        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items);
            temp += Convert.ToDecimal(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());

        }
        return temp;

    }
```

Comment: Why he needs the sum parameter if the method returns it? The only purpose of this method is to sum the listbox items.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Because it's added to?

Comment: yeah he added with sum

Comment: @GillBates: then he should add the result of this method where he uses it. But i doubt that he needs to add it anyway. He just thought that he needs to pass the variable that will be returned(like `out`).

Comment: Probably, but that's not the question in this case.

Comment: I have added temporary local variable for better code

Answer (score 0):

Your message expects 2 parameters: random and sum. You call it with only one parameter. That is exactly what the error message says.

Answer (score 0):

You dont want random parameter as you are not using it

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
    Listbox1opgeteld(sum); 

}
public decimal Listbox1opgeteld(decimal sum) 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items);
        sum += Convert.ToDecimal(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());

    }
    return sum;

}
```